# bash find exec: rename files and preserve optional extensions?

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I want to find all files that match a pattern and append a string to the prefix, preserving the extension if it exists. Some of the files have extensions and others don't.

Desired transform:

```
tools-win/foo.exe => tools-win/foo_bar.exe
tools-osx/foo     => tools-osx/foo_bar
```

Is there a way to do this with bash parameter expressions? My current attempt is:

```
find . -path 'tools-*/*' \
    -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}_$2.${1##.}"' _ {} bar \;`
```

This works on files that have extensions, but captures the entire prefix for files that have no extensions:

```
tools-win/foo.exe => tools-win/foo_bar.exe
tools-osx/foo     => tools-osx/foo_bar.foo
```

Is there a single parameter expression I can use here that handles both cases?

Comment: If you are sure anything ending in .??? is an "extension", pipe the output of `find` to a `while read` loop that does the swaps in neat steps. If not, maybe make a table of extensions to preserve? Sub in the append string in front of those if they exist, or just stick it on the end if they don't.

Comment: Yeah, I could also do multiple passes etc. I was mostly just curious if there was some parameter expression magic that does everything in one line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner shell script can parse out the prefix by stripping everything including and after the final `.`, and then the suffix by stripping the prefix out of the original string. The final string can be assembled with standard concatenation:

```
PREFIX=${1%.*}
SUFFIX=${1##"${PREFIX}"}
FINAL=${PREFIX}_bar${SUFFIX}
```

Note that if `${PREFIX}` is identical to the input string, `${SUFFIX}` will be empty.

So while it's not a one-liner inside `sh`, an invocation that only calls `find -exec` once without pipes looks like this:

```
find "${PATH_TO_SEARCH}" -path "${PATH_TO_SEARCH}/tools-*/*" \
    -execdir sh -c 'p=${1%.*};s=${1##"${p}"};mv "$1" "${p}_$2${s}"' sh {} bar \;`
```

Answer (score 1):

A first simplistic pass:

Formatted:

```
find | 
  while read -r f
  do case $f in
     *.???) echo mv "$f" "${f%.???}_bar${f##${f%.???}}" ;;
         *) echo mv "$f" "${f}_bar"                     ;;
     esac
  done
```

The magic mess is `"${f%.???}_bar${f##${f%.???}}"` -
`${f%.???}` is the filename without the simplistically-defined extension.
`${f##${f%.???}}` is the simplistically-defined extension used to remove everything *else* from the front of the file, so it *is* the (complicatedly derived) aforementioned "simplistically-defined extension". :)

This should create no subshells (aside from the `find`), so it ought to be very efficient.

---

## CAVEAT SCRIPTOR

The significant flaw is in the `.???` which will likely NOT do what you wanted when it hits the file names `x.v1.2.3` and renames it to `x.v1_bar.2.3`. This could likely be fixed, but without seeing your data I didn't want to elaborate it incorrectly.

---

Still, it *could* be squished to one line -

```
  find | while read -r f; do case $f in *.???) echo mv "$f" "${f%.???}_bar${f##${f%.???}}" ;; *) echo mv "$f" "${f}_bar";; esac; done
```

I actively avoided trying to work all that *into* the find. I recommend piping this whole thing to a file and scanning for craziness before executing it. If everything works, or there are few enough exceptions that maybe you can just manually edit those, then you can just execute the file.

Comment: This works and is straightforward but doesn't roll everything up into a single parameter expression. I'm mostly curious about whether there's an incantation using #/##, %/%%, ^/^^ that I can just throw at find -exec sh -c ...

Comment: If `${f%.???}_bar${f##${f%.???}}"` isn't already too complex for sanity, please consult your doctor. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very simply with `rename`, a.k.a. `Perl rename`. It masquerades under different names in different package managers/ operating systems.

It has an `-X` switch that removes the extension and then adds it back later, and an `-a` switch that allows you to add strings as postfixes to the current name. So to add `_bar` to the base part of the filename before the extension, on all PNG files, use:

```
rename -X -a "_bar" *.png
```

It can do a million more things:

- add `--dry-run` to see what it would do without actually doing anything, **this is beautiful**
- use `$N` to introduce a sequential counter into filenames
- it automatically detects collisions when two changes would result in a file being overwritten and warns you before doing any harm - **this is invaluable**
- you can pass it entire Perl scripts to process filenames in the most complicated way you can imagine

---

You can test if your `rename` is the Perl one I am referring to with:

```
file $(which rename)
```

and if it is correct, you will see it is a Perl executable. If you find the correct one for your OS, maybe you would add a comment to this answer saying which package you installed to get it.

---

On macOS, you can install the `rename` tool I am referring to with **homebrew** as follows:

```
brew install rename
```

Comment: Rename was my first choice, and this is really the right top-level answer. Unfortunately, this needs to run on computers that I don't manage that don't have it installed, and installing is infeasible.

Comment: It's just a Perl script no different from one you might write yourself. Can't you copy the file and paste it into a place where you put your own scripts? It's ok - don't let me bully you - I am just saying :-)

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth the effort for what I'm doing when there are (admittedly gross) bash solutions that work...